# How to fix auto color for cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I installed cygwin 3.1.7 64bit from setup 2.905 and if I don't use `grep --color=always` I don't see colored output in a terminal, i.e. `grep --color=auto` does not work correctly in my terminal (default mintty) and looks like `grep --color=never`. How can I fix this?

I'm not sure that is the same topic, but Windows maven 3.6.3 output has color control sequences, however they are not rendered correctly. I thought this was working in 3.6.0 already, although Google states that a library needs to be updated to have that. Example output: `[←[1;34mINFO←[m] ←[1;32mBUILD SUCCESS←[m`

Comment: please provide a test case and the expected output. `--color=always` and `--color=auto` produce the same output on my system using a Cygwin terminal

Comment: Hi @matzeri: That is also my target/expectation, i.e. my output from `--color=auto` currently looks like `--color=never`, but it should look like `--color=always`. What test case do you mean, a screenshot?

Comment: I was wrong. `--color=auto` is equal to `always` if the output is a terminal. If the output is a pipe the effect is different.

Comment: Yes of course, so I guess that is broken, why is my terminal recognized as pipe? How is that verification done? Can I do a check for this verification?

Comment: What is your Terminal ? Is Cygwin Terminal working ?

Comment: I updated the question, I use default mintty and no I have the issue with this terminal.

Comment: For a colleague with cygwin 3.1.7 32bit from setup 2.905 states this is working for him, i.e. this could be an issue for 64bit. Any idea how to verify this in depth?

Answer (score 4):

I found https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22616 and verified that my `TERM` variable was set to xterm. After changing to `cygwin` (`export TERM=cygwin`) maven output was correct. I still don't understand why this has impact, i.e. for a collegue this is also xterm and working in cygwin 32bit.

Also I don't accept this answer, because I want to understand the core reason for this and because my workaround also breaks my Pos1 and End key mappings to work in zsh (jumpt to start of the line or end of line in console).